# Why is my Nearest neighbour outputting higher value in a equally spaced grid?

Tags: qgis, raster, point, interpolation

So I got a point layer which is equally spaced 0,5x0,5. When I run the nearest neighbour and accounting for the extent so that the raster cells are centered, I get this result. I got maybe five areas with this big difference. The cell says -1,98 and the original pointdata is -1,5.

Shouldn't Nearest neighbour output more or less the same value of a equally spaced grid if the raster cell is centered? The output of the data is the same resolution as the grid, 0,5x0,5.

I am using Qgis for this with SAGAs tool.[image]

Comment: Check the image information from the Layer - Properties - Information. Do you see there `AREA_OR_POINT=Area` of `AREA_OR_POINT=Point`?

Comment: It is saved as a .sdat but when I export it as a TIF it says "AREA_OR_POINT=Area"

Comment: In that case the anchor point of the pixel is at the top left corner of the pixel. So even it seems that the points are exactly in the middle of individual pixels for the algorithm they may actually have four nearest neighbors. I am not sure about this, but try what happens if you slide the image so that points are at the corners of the pixels.

Comment: What does AREA_OR_POINT=Area of AREA_OR_POINT=Point mean? I am new to GIS. 
Now I tried using the layer extent without changingthe extent, but then the points are not centered over the raster cells and also it other cells deviates from the original point grid. 
This is my layer extent from selecting use layer extent from point gird
110563.25,110617.25,6235835.25,6235905.75